# How to print every second digit in C

Tags: c, for-loop, nested

My task is to print every second digit of given long in C. 
My code looks like this:

```
long credit;
int mod, mod1, var;

int main(void)
{
    credit = get_long("n: \n");
    for (mod = -1; credit > 0; credit /= 10)
    {
        mod = credit % 10;
        for(mod1 = 1; mod1 <= mod; mod1+=2)
        {
            for (var = 1; var <= mod1; var++)
            {
                if(var == mod)
                {
                    printf("%i ", var);
                }
             }
         }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately it prints only odd numbers from given long. No matter how many even numbers is between. 
I wonder if the way I have chosen (nesting for loops + if statement) is proper way of doing it.

**NOTE: I am not looking for ready solution. I am looking for hints as I wouldl ike to discover solution on my own.**

Comment: Just enter a string and print every second digit. It makes no sense to type in a number digit by digit, convert that to an integer, and pick it back apart to what you entered in the first place. It's a card number anyway, which happens to be numeric, and it's not as though you are going to sum the numbers of various cards or other arithmetical operation. Moreover, as an integer, how many characters were entered? How do you detect a leading zero digit(s), which is significant?

Comment: *"I am not looking for ready solution. I am looking for hints as I wouldl ike to discover solution on my own."* - That's not what SO is for. This is a place for QA-pairs.

Comment: You need to actually ask a question that we can answer. Do you have an algorithm worked out? If not, ask for specific help working one out. If so, add it to your question and ask for help converting it to code.

Comment: @klutt I guess what OP means is, that her/his question should not be interpreted as "Write Code for me" question. Thus, s/he tries to deescalate. Maybe based upon made experience.

Comment: BTW: Don't use the CS50 header if you aren't forced to so. Its use is deprecated.

Comment: I didn't read your piece of code, but when I look at your question "I want to write even numbers" and your problem "I write odd numbers", my first guess would be that everything is correct, except your starting point.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yes, I understood that. I'm simply pointing out that SO is not for tutoring.

Comment: @piotrektnw And yes, I have to agree with Robert here. CS50 should not be used. It just adds to the confusion when learning C.

Comment: @klutt RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio,
I see but I am taking CS50 course so it gives me possibility to test my code according to their needs.

Comment: @piotrektnw I've never understood those who are in charge of CS50. Do they really think that their library is a good idea?

Comment: @klutt Well, I am beginner. I cannot say a word about their library as I have no comparison for that

Comment: @piotrektnw Hehe, true. My objection is this. They created that library so that you can learn C without worrying about pointers and such. But dealing with pointers is essential to what programming in C means. C is a great language to learn how a computer works at low level, but if you strip away all those things that are the core of C, then what's the point? If the goal of that course is to introduce people to programming, there are far better languages to use.

Comment: @klutt I see. On next steps CS50 covers other languages like Python or JavaScript. Few months ago I have started with learning Python as my first language, but I have understood that at the beginning of my path with programming I need more systematized way of learning than watching youtube tutorials..

Comment: regarding: ` I'm simply pointing out that SO is not for tutoring`  I do a LOT of tutoring on SO,  mostly in the form of `OT` (Off Topic)` comments

Answer (score 1):

well, you can get the last digit by taking modulo 10 and then you can get rid of 2 digits by dividing the number by 100 and if you do this until the number is equal to 0 you get every second digit, like this:

```
x /= 10; //just offsetting it by one more digit (so you get even and not odd numbers)

while(x > 0)
{
    printf("%lld", x % 10);
    x /= 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will solve the problem without so many loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BASE (10) /* fits any base between 2 and 16 */

#ifndef EVENS
#define EVENS 0
#endif

char *print_each_2nd(
        unsigned x,  /* value to extract digits. */
        char *buf,   /* buffer to use as workpad */
        size_t sz)   /* size of previous buffer  */
{
    buf += sz; /* we go backwards, from the end of the buffer */
    while (x) {
        int remainder = x % (BASE*BASE); 
        
        if (!sz) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Not enough buffer space\n");
            return NULL;
        }
#if EVENS
        remainder /= BASE;
#endif
        *--buf = "0123456789abcdef"[remainder % BASE];
        sz--;

        x /= BASE*BASE;
    }
    return buf;
} /* print_each_2nd */

int main()
{
    char workpad[20];

    unsigned number = 123456789;
    printf("original: %d, alternates: %s\n", 
           number,
           print_each_2nd(number, 
                   workpad, sizeof workpad));
} /* main */
```

Is a complete example that you can build and test.